# ¿Por qué se dice "¿qué se te ofrece?" y no "¿qué te ofrezco?"?

Tags: gramática, expresiones, verbo-pronominal

Llevo más o menos tres años hablando español, dos de los cuales viví en Mexico. Pero algo que sigo sin entender es por qué, si es que hay alguna razón, decimos **¿Qué se te ofrece?** y no *¿Qué te ofrezco?* o *¿Qué te puedo ofrecer?*

Cada vez que escucho esta frase es en una situación en la que no cabe duda quién va a ofrecer algo. Se me hace muy raro que la oración no se dirija directamente a la persona. ¿Alguien me puede explicar por qué es así? ¿Hay más oraciones parecidas?

Comment: Creo que se use el `se` pasivo para mostrar cortesía.  Significa algo como `What appeals to you enough to order it?  or `What is being ordered by you?`

Comment: En este caso se utiliza para todo lo contrario, la connotación es mucho más coloquial.

Comment: @EmilioGort No creo que sea así. Cuando quitas el dativo ético de la frase, esta debe conservar su sentido, y en este caso no lo conserva. Observemos que "¿Qué te ofrece?" habla de que una tercera persona le está ofreciendo algo a tu interlocutor, y no es para nada lo que se quiere expresar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yo diría que depende del nivel de cortesía de la frase y del significado que le quieras dar.

"¿Qué se te ofrece?" es el uso más habitual y no tiene las mismas connotaciones que las otras dos frases. Vendría a significar "¿Qué quieres?" y no necesariamente tienes tú que estar ofreciendo nada.

"¿Qué te puedo ofrecer?" es mucho más educado y en este caso si que estás poniendo a disposición del receptor tus recursos. Sí que estás ofreciendo algo.

Por otra parte, si bien "¿Qué te ofrezco?" está bien formulado y tiene significado, no se usa habitualmente. Vamos, yo jamás lo he escuchado en ningún contexto social.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Answer (score 7):

Entiendo que en la frase  qué se te ofrece  hay una connotación impersonal que es justamente la que se quiere transmitir. Es como decir:

> ¿Qué se te puede ofrecer a través de mí?

Si decimos *¿Qué te ofrezco?* o *¿Qué te puedo ofrecer?* está claro que el ofrecimiento depende absolutamente de mí.

En la frase que nos ocupa se da a entender que el ofrecimiento puede ser realizado por otra persona. ¡Gran lengua la española!

Comment: Buena respuesta, user. Te animo a que te registres y sigas contribuyendo en [spanish.se]. ¡Bienvenido!

Comment: +1: Coincido con la idea del matiz impersonal.

Answer (score 2):

*Ofrece* es en este caso la tercera persona del singular (usted/él/ella)

> - ¿Qué se te ofrece (a él)?
> - ¿Qué se te ofrece (a ella)?
> - ¿Qué se te ofrece (a usted)?

Pero el uso de *te* como complemento indirecto se emplea para sustituir *a ti*.

> - ¿Qué se te ofrece (a ti)?

No es incorrecto, pero no tan formal como al usar *le*

> - ¿Qué se le ofrece (a usted)?
> - ¿Qué se le ofrece (a él)?
> - ¿Qué se le ofrece (a ella)?

En

> - ¿Qué te puedo ofrecer? 
>     Esta basada en la construcción *poder+infinitivo*, *perífrasis modal de posibilidad*, informa de la actitud del hablante. Válida y formal.

---

Ejemplo similar: **¿Qué se te ocurre?**.

Entre conocidos es normal *¿Qué se te ocurre (a ti)?* o *¿Qué te ocurre (a ti)?* pero no le diremos *¿Qué se le ocurre (a usted)?*, solo cuando manifiestas un gran respeto a la otra persona.

Igual pasa en *¿Qué te ofrezco (a ti)?*, entre amigos sí lo diré. Se parece más a una sentencia exclamativa e interrogativa a la vez.

*¡Qué te ocurre?* contra *¡Qué le ocurre?*.

Así pues añadiría a tus ejemplos *¿Qué le ofrezco?* como válida y formal.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Qué se te ofrece?

es usado por los vendedores, comunmente. Ellos *ofrecen* mercancía y preguntan qué, entre los productos que venden. Significa entonces *¿qué le vendo?*, en tal contexto.

*¿Qué se te ofrece?*, en otras palabras, significa *¿qué necesitas?*.